# Why CAT 5 cable is run through electrical box with blank faceplate

Tags: electrical, drywall, new-home, network

The two cables seen here have very little slack. [image: Two taught cat 5 cables running through electrical box]
The house was built in 1998 in Texas in case it offers any clues.

Any idea why this is here?

Comment: Beware the wiring layout. In 1998 people still did landlines, and telephone wiring can daisy-chain, while ethernet needs to be a "star" unless you have switches at any point it wants to "chain on" from.

Answer (score 2):

The person that put the cables in ran drops for that location. There should be some slack so it could be used. Normally there are loops if you pull on the wires there should be some slack as a tight run through the back of a box would be useless. Give the wires a bit of a tug to see if they are just stuck from the paint

Comment: I agree, though putting them through both knockouts instead of just coiling them is a bit strange, but hardly the strangest thing anyone's done.

Comment: Putting them through both knockouts might have made sense if this wiring was intended for phones rather than ethernet -- in that case, it was probably wired with daisy-chaining in mind, and the wires are passing through this box on the way to another location.  It's probably intended to just cut the wire and splice in a pigtail if a phone jack is needed at this location.  Of course, that's not very helpful if you're wanting to repurpose them to be ethernet.

Comment: Ok just to say no box is or was ever required for this , so if there a new slack you got what was paid for some ??? Pulling cable and not a pro job just saying